# Determining type of map output

Tags: swift

I am trying to determine what the type of .map's output is here:

```
func position(rows: Int, cols: Int) -> [Position] {
    return (0 ..< rows)
        .map {
            zip(
                [Int](repeating: $0, count: cols) ,
                0 ..< cols
            )
        }
}
```

I know that zip returns a Zip2Sequence instance, which in this case is tuple pairs of (integer array, countable integer range).

I get that map alters elements in a sequence, but I thought it took multiple arguments like `val in val * 2` and here zip is the only argument... so is it just adding the output of zip to an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the `map` is of type `Array<Zip2Sequence<Array<Int>, CountableRange<Int>>>` which is essentially `[[(Int, Int)]]`.

I found this by assigning the result of the `map` to `let result` and printing `print(type(of: result))`.

`map` transforms your original sequence `(0 ..< rows)` into an array that will have `rows` items.  `zip` will be called with each element of `(0 ..< rows)` in turn which is represented by `$0`.

It will be more useful if you wrap the `zip` call with `Array()` to turn the zip sequence into an actual array that you can examine easily:

Example:

```
let rows = 2
let cols = 3

let result = (0 ..< rows)
    .map { val in
        Array(zip(
            [Int](repeating: val, count: cols) ,
            0 ..< cols
        ))
}

print(result)
// [[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)], [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of `(0 ..< rows)` is `CountableRange<Int>`:

```
  1> (0 ..< 10)
$R0: (CountableRange<Int>) = {
  lowerBound = 0
  upperBound = 10
}
```

`CountableRange` conforms to `Sequence`, so it has a `map` method. This `map` method takes one argument, a closure.

A closure is a function. In general, a function has zero or more arguments and a one return value. For `CountableRange<Int>.map`, the closure is required to take one argument of type `Int` and can return any type.

There are several ways to write closures in Swift. The shortest way, which your example uses, is to write a single expression inside `{ ... }`. Here's what [*The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4)*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) says:

> #### Implicit Returns from Single-Expression Closures
>
> Single-expression closures can implicitly return the result of their single expression by omitting the return keyword from their declaration[…]

Furthermore, if the closure takes arguments, the closure can refer to them using shorthand names (`$0`, `$1`, etc.) **instead of** giving them explicit names (e.g. `val in ...`). From the book again:

> #### Shorthand Argument Names
>
> Swift automatically provides shorthand argument names to inline closures, which can be used to refer to the values of the closure’s arguments by the names `$0`, `$1`, `$2`, and so on.
>
> If you use these shorthand argument names within your closure expression, you can omit the closure’s argument list from its definition, and the number and type of the shorthand argument names will be inferred from the expected function type. The `in` keyword can also be omitted, because the closure expression is made up entirely of its body[…]

Looking at the `map` method call, we can see that its closure contains a single expression (a call to `zip`) with implicit return, and it uses `$0` to refer to its single argument.

The `zip` function takes two arguments, each of which must be a `Sequence`, and the `zip` function returns a `Zip2Sequence`. In your example, the first argument to `zip` is `[Int](repeating: $0, count: cols)`, which has type `[Int]` (or `Array<Int>`). The second argument to `zip` is `0 ..< cols`, which is another `CountableRange<Int>`. So the type returned by this call to `zip` is `Zip2Sequence<[Int], CountableRange<Int>>`, which is a somewhat inscrutable type that generates tuples `(Int, Int)`.

The type returned by `map` is an `Array` containing the values returned by its closure argument. Thus the type returned by `map` in this case is `[Zip2Sequence<[Int], CountableRange<Int>>]`.

If you want something more scrutable, you can wrap the call to `zip` in the `Array` constructor:

```
func position(rows: Int, cols: Int) -> [[(Int, Int)]] {
    return (0 ..< rows)
        .map {
            Array(zip(
                [Int](repeating: $0, count: cols) ,
                0 ..< cols
            ))
        }
}
```

The `Array` constructor takes any `Sequence` and turns it into an `Array`. So the `Zip2Sequence<[Int], CountableRange<Int>>` is turned into `[(Int, Int)]`, and `map` produces an `Array` whose elements are that type, thus producing an array of arrays of pairs of `Int`, or `[[(Int, Int)]]`.

Comment: thank you for the shorthand and expression explanations!